# Emulator not Starting - Hanging on UpdateChecker skipped version check

Tags: android, emulation

I have searched everywhere but nothing works for me so far. I have increased the available RAM to 1.5gb, still nothing. Not sure where I am going wrong.

I tried installing Genymotion but all that did was not work either (VirtualBox had errors where upon starting an emulator it would come up with xxx Killed by Signal 9)

I'm running this in Android Studio and keep getting this error:

```
C:\Users\Nikita\AppData\Local\Android\sdk1\tools\emulator.exe -netdelay none     -netspeed full -avd Nexus_9_API_22
emulator: device fd:632
HAXM is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
creating window 230 56 1178 884
emulator: UpdateChecker: skipped version check
```

It hangs on this and nothing else happens. I've left it for 30minutes to see if that will help but to no avail.

Comment: Increase the RAM to 2 or 4 gig? Restart the computer? My best advice would be to buy a device. The emulator is a POS.

Comment: is the emaulator on other devices working fine besides nexus 9? Try creating one for nexus S.

Comment: I tried increasing the RAM to 2gb and restarting my computer, all that happened was I got this message:

emulator: WARNING: Requested RAM size of 2048MB is too large for your environment, and is reduced to 1536MB.

I will try another emulator but I think all had the same thing